# How to use NSDayCalendarUnit in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'm trying to setup a UILocalNotification object's repeatInterval attribute. It works well with NSDayCalendarUnit, but I need to set a repeat interval of every three days.
I've tried NSDayCalendarUnit + 3, but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
No, that is not working either. If I schedule

```
localNotify.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit
```

the log shows:

```
<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x71aabf0>{fire date = 2010-07-16 02:40:00 -0400, time zone = US/Eastern (EDT) offset -14400 (Daylight), repeat interval = 16, next fire date = 2010-07-16 02:40:00 -0400}
```

If I schedule

```
localNotify.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit*3
```

the log shows:

```
<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x71b4ae0>{fire date = 2010-07-16 02:30:00 -0400, time zone = US/Eastern (EDT) offset -14400 (Daylight), repeat interval = 48, next fire date = 2010-07-17 03:30:00 -0400}
```

So repeat interval goes forward by one hour on the following day, instead of what I want which is for it to repeat in 3 days time.
Any suggestions?

Comment: +3 is a bad choice (you're making implicit assumptions about what the underlying units are). Much better is *3, but even then I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

`NSDayCalendarUnit` is an enumeration constant; arithmetic has no sensible meaning in relation to it.

I do not believe the current local notifications API allows for the interval you want. You should [file a bug report](http://bugreporter.apple.com) with Apple and request more fine-grained control of local notifications.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that. In the meantime, do you know of any workaround for this?

Comment: As I said, I don't think there's any way to. It's a limitation of the current `UILocalNotification` API. Sorry.

Comment: I could probably figure something out if I knew a way to suppress a notification (but not cancel it altogether), that way I could schedule the repeatInterval with NSDayCalendarUnit, and just suppress notifications until a date I choose. 

So all I need now is a way to suppress UILocalNotification!

Comment: You can cancel notifications from within your app, but since you can't execute code when your app is not running... yeah.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use NSDayCalendarUnit*3 to mean 3 days. Does it work ?